# Google appscript does not recognize Chromium based Edge

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, microsoft-edge, user-agent, google-apps-script-addon

I am trying to detect Chromium based Edge browser in google slides addon.

#### Code.gs

```
function onInstall(event) {
    onOpen(event);
}

function onOpen(event) {
    SlidesApp.getUi().createAddonMenu()
        .addItem('Open the sidebar', '_showSidebar')
        .addToUi();
    _showSidebar();
}

function _showSidebar() {
    var ui = HtmlService
        .createHtmlOutputFromFile('index')
        .setTitle('Test add-on');
    SlidesApp.getUi().showSidebar(ui);
}
```

#### index.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    
    <script>
       const onButtonClick = () => {
         console.log(window.navigator.userAgent);
       }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="onButtonClick()">Click me</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Clicking on the button in sidebar logs to console:

```
5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36
```

But when I manually type `window.navigator.userAgent` to browser console log looks differently (`Edg/84.0.522.49` is missing):

```
5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36 Edg/84.0.522.49
```

Comment: My MS Edge 85.0.564.44 no longer overrides the UA string on docs.google.com domain. "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.83 Safari/537.36 Edg/85.0.564.44"

Comment: I tested my code on latest edge version (MS Edge 85.0.564.44) and it works :)

Comment: Extension, here we come!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is that your Google Slides addon/sidebar is running inside an iframe which is hosted on `docs.google.com`.

The new Chromium based Microsoft Edge browser [overrides User-Agent on some sites to maximize compatibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/web-platform/user-agent-string#user-agent-overrides). If you open `edge://compat/useragent` in your Edge you will see that the `docs.google.com` is listed in that "User agent overrides" list: [image]

To disable the user agent overrides functionality, you may run the Microsoft Edge executable using the following command line argument:
`--disable-domain-action-user-agent-override`