# Edge Extension Submission Fail due to Distinct Function & Value

Tags: microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-extension

I am trying to publish edge extension (unlisted for testing only) but it is failing due to the following reason:

```
1.1.2 
Distinct Function & Value; Accurate Representation

The product references another browser. Please remove the
instances. Steps to reproduce: [steps]
```

[image: Reason why publishing failed]
**The extension's aim**
is to extend our Google Slides editor add-on. Add-on is able to detect if the extension is installed or if it's possible to
install it. Currently we only support Chrome so if we detect that we don't have the extension installed and we are in Chrome browser, Google Slides sidebar displays the message which is suggesting to install Chrome extension.

Reason which is causing submission to fail is **not even caused by the extension** itself, it's different application (Google Slides add-on) which is referencing other browser.

We would like to display different messages for Chrome and Edge browsers but currently we are not able to differentiate between Chromium Edge and Chrome browser due to (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63193042/3577217)):

> The new Chromium based Microsoft Edge browser overrides User-Agent on some sites to maximize compatibility. If you open edge://compat/useragent in your Edge you will see that the docs.google.com is listed in that "User agent overrides" list

I emailed to `reportap@microsoft.com` and was told that I need to publis an extension as hidden and add this information as a test notes but still extension submission failed. Is there any workaround for publishing this extension only for testing?

Comment: I want to confirm with you at which step for [publishing an extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions-chromium/publish/publish-extension) you get this error? I also try to check the [Microsoft Edge Addons Catalog Developer Policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions-chromium/store-policies/developer-policies) and it looks like policy number and description is not matching in your description. Did you also get some other errors? The only description without any code sample will not give much idea.

Comment: I get this error during validation. I received an email from `msftpc@microsoft.com` with Failed result and in **Critical Validations** section  is the reason I mentioned `1.1.2 
Distinct Function & Value; Accurate Representation`. I added a picture of our Google slides add-on. As I mentioned, add-on is different application and this is the reason why my submission is failing.